# How to swipe delete recyclerview items stored in firestore using kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

Below is my app_bar_main file which contains a toolbar and fab to create boards.
This layout file is included from main_content, which has a recycler view.

**app_bar_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Manageio.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Manageio.PopUpOverlay" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/main_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_createBoard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_add"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**main_content**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/lightPrimaryColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_boardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:item_layout="@layout/item_board"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tv_noBoardsAvailable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/boogaloo"
            android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
            android:text="No Boards Available!"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now whenever I click on fab it takes me to CreateBoardActivity which creates boards and store it in the firestore

**CreateBoardActivity**

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.manageio.R
import com.example.manageio.firebase.FirestoreClass
import com.example.manageio.models.Board
import com.example.manageio.utils.Constants
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_create_board.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_profile.*
import java.io.IOException

class CreateBoardActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private var mSelectedImageFileUri : Uri?= null

    private lateinit var mUserName : String

    private var mBoardImageURL : String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_board)

        if(intent.hasExtra(Constants.NAME)){
            mUserName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.NAME).toString()
        }

        iv_boardImage.setOnClickListener {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                Constants.showImageChooser(this)
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    Constants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
                )
            }
        }

        createBoard_createBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if(mSelectedImageFileUri!=null){
                uploadBoardImage()
            }else{
                showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
                createBoard()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createBoard(){
        val assignedUserArrayList : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        assignedUserArrayList.add(getCurrentUserId())

        var board = Board(
            createBoard_et_boardName.text.toString(),
            mBoardImageURL,
            mUserName,
            assignedUserArrayList
        )

        FirestoreClass().createBoard(this,board)
    }

    private fun uploadBoardImage(){
        showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

        val sRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            .reference.child(
                "BOARD_IMAGE" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." +
                        Constants.getFileExtension(this,mSelectedImageFileUri!!)
            )

        sRef.putFile(mSelectedImageFileUri!!).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
            Log.i(
                "FirebaseBoardImageUrl",
                taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.toString()
            )
            taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                Log.i("DownloadBoardImageUrl", uri.toString())
                mBoardImageURL = uri.toString()
                createBoard()
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(this@CreateBoardActivity, exception.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            hideProgressDialog()
        }


    }

    fun boardCreatedSuccessfully(){
        hideProgressDialog()
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
        finish()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == Constants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Constants.showImageChooser(this)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "You denied the permission for storage.You can allow it from settings",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == Constants.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && data!!.data != null) {
            mSelectedImageFileUri = data.data
            try {
                Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(mSelectedImageFileUri)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.color.lightPrimaryColor)
                    .into(iv_boardImage)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**FireStoreClass**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.manageio.activities.*
import com.example.manageio.models.Board
import com.example.manageio.models.User
import com.example.manageio.utils.Constants
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.SetOptions

class FirestoreClass {
    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

   
    fun getBoardDetails(activity: TaskListActivity, documentId: String) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.BOARDS)
            .document(documentId)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val board = document.toObject(Board::class.java)!!
                board.documentId = document.id
                activity.boardDetails(board)

            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                activity.hideProgressDialog()
                Log.e("FirestoreClass", "Error with exception ", e)
            }
    }

    fun createBoard(activity: CreateBoardActivity, board: Board) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.BOARDS)
            .document()
            .set(board, SetOptions.merge())
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Board Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                activity.boardCreatedSuccessfully()
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                activity.hideProgressDialog()
                Log.e("FirestoreClass", "Error with exception ", e)
            }
    }

    fun getBoardsList(activity: MainActivity) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.BOARDS)
            .whereArrayContains(Constants.ASSIGNED_TO, getCurrentUserId())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val boardlist: ArrayList<Board> = ArrayList()
                for (i in document.documents) {
                    val board = i.toObject(Board::class.java)!!
                    board.documentId = i.id
                    boardlist.add(board)
                }

                activity.populateBoardsListToUI(boardlist)
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                activity.hideProgressDialog()
                Log.e("FireStoreClass", "Error while creating board.", e)
            }
    }

    
    fun updateUserProfileData(activity: Activity, userHashMap: HashMap<String, Any>) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserId())
            .update(userHashMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.i("FirestoreClass", "Profile Data Updated Successfully")
                Toast.makeText(
                    activity,
                    "You profile has been updated successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                when(activity){
                    is MainActivity ->{
                        activity.tokenUpdateSuccess()
                    }
                    is ProfileActivity ->{
                        activity.profileUpdateSuccess()
                    }
                }

            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                when(activity){
                    is MainActivity ->{
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                    is ProfileActivity ->{
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                }
                Log.e("FirestoreClass", "Error while updating profile", e)
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error while updating profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

    fun loadUserData(activity: Activity, readBoardsList: Boolean = false) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserId())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                val loggedInUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!

                when (activity) {
                    is LoginActivity -> {
                        activity.loginSuccess(loggedInUser)
                    }
                    is MainActivity -> {
                        activity.updateNavigationUserDetails(loggedInUser, readBoardsList)
                    }
                    is ProfileActivity -> {
                        activity.setUserDataInUi(loggedInUser)
                    }
                }


            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                when (activity) {
                    is LoginActivity -> {
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                    is MainActivity -> {
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                }
                Log.e("FirestoreClass", "Error with exception $e")
            }
    }

    fun getCurrentUserId(): String {
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        var currentUserId = ""
        if (currentUser != null) {
            currentUserId = currentUser.uid
        }

        return currentUserId
    }

    

    fun assignMemberToBoard(activity: MembersActivity, board : Board, user : User){
        val assignedToHashmap = HashMap<String,Any>()
        assignedToHashmap[Constants.ASSIGNED_TO] = board.assignedTo
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.BOARDS)
            .document(board.documentId)
            .update(assignedToHashmap)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                activity.memberAssignSuccess(user)
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                activity.hideProgressDialog()
                Log.e("FirestoreClass", "Error while creating board",e)
            }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.manageio.R
import com.example.manageio.adapters.BoardItemsAdapter
import com.example.manageio.firebase.FirestoreClass
import com.example.manageio.models.Board
import com.example.manageio.models.User
import com.example.manageio.utils.Constants
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

import com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getInstance
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.app_bar_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.main_content.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_main.*

class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    companion object{
        const val MY_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE : Int = 99
        const val CREATE_BOARD_REQUEST_CODE : Int =98
    }

    private lateinit var mUserName : String
    private lateinit var mSharedPreferences : SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setUpActionBar()
        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MANAGEIO_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val tokenUpdated = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.FCM_TOKEN_UPDATED,false)

        if(tokenUpdated){
            showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
            FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this@MainActivity,true)
        }
        else{
            FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(tokenUpdated).addOnSuccessListener(this@MainActivity){
                instanceIdResult ->
                updateFCMTOKEN(instanceIdResult.token)
            }
        }
        // TODO Check 1
//        FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this , true)

        fab_createBoard.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,CreateBoardActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(Constants.NAME,mUserName)
            startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_BOARD_REQUEST_CODE)

        }

    }

    fun populateBoardsListToUI(boardsList : ArrayList<Board>){
        hideProgressDialog()

        if(boardsList.size > 0){
            rv_boardList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_noBoardsAvailable.visibility = View.GONE

            rv_boardList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            rv_boardList.setHasFixedSize(true)

            val adapter = BoardItemsAdapter(this,boardsList)
            rv_boardList.adapter = adapter

            adapter.setOnClickListener(object :BoardItemsAdapter.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(position: Int, model: Board) {
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,TaskListActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.DOCUMENT_ID,model.documentId)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            })

        }else{
            rv_boardList.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_noBoardsAvailable.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun setUpActionBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar_main_activity)
        toolbar_main_activity.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_nav_menu)
        toolbar_main_activity.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            toggleDrawer()
        }
    }

    private fun toggleDrawer() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }
    }

    fun updateNavigationUserDetails(user: User, readBoardsList : Boolean){
        hideProgressDialog()
        mUserName = user.name
        Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(user.image)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nav_user)
            .into(iv_userImage);

        tv_username.text = user.name

        if(readBoardsList){
            showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
            FirestoreClass().getBoardsList(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            doubleBackToExit()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == MY_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE){
            FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this)
        }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CREATE_BOARD_REQUEST_CODE){
            FirestoreClass().getBoardsList(this)
        }
        else{
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Cancelled")
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.nav_my_profile -> {
                startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity,ProfileActivity::class.java),
                    MY_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE)
            }

            R.id.nav_logout -> {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                mSharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply()
                val intent = Intent(this,WelcomeActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()

            }

        }
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    }
```

**BoardItemsAdapter

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.manageio.R
import com.example.manageio.firebase.FirestoreClass
import com.example.manageio.models.Board
import com.example.manageio.utils.Constants
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_board.view.*

open class BoardItemsAdapter(private val context: Context,private var list: ArrayList<Board>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){


    private var onClickListener : OnClickListener ?= null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_board,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position]
        if(holder is MyViewHolder){
            Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(model.image)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.color.lightPrimaryColor)
                .into(holder.itemView.iv_itemBoardImage)

            holder.itemView.tv_name.text = model.name
            holder.itemView.tv_createdBy.text = "Created By: ${model.createdBy}"

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if(onClickListener!=null){
                    onClickListener!!.onClick(position,model)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnClickListener{
        fun onClick(position: Int,model : Board)
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener){
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }



    private class MyViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

**Board(model)**

package com.example.manageio.models

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable

```
data class Board(
    val name : String = "",
    val image : String = "",
    val createdBy : String = "",
    val assignedTo : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(),
    var documentId : String = "",
    var taskList : ArrayList<Task> = ArrayList()

) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.createStringArrayList()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.createTypedArrayList(Task.CREATOR)!!
    )


    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(parcel){
        parcel.writeString(name)
        parcel.writeString(image)
        parcel.writeString(createdBy)
        parcel.writeStringList(assignedTo)
        parcel.writeString(documentId)
        parcel.writeTypedList(taskList)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Board> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Board {
            return Board(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Board?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

And then the created boards are shown in the main activity
Please refer these images

[Firestore Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdH9Z.png)

[Main activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6mgm.jpg)

**Not what I want is whenever I swipe one recycler view list then it should be deleted .**
How to implement it so it also gets deleted from firestore?

And please don't mind the other functions which are not important. Actually it is my first time asking so i pasted it all there

Comment: Check documentation for deleting from firestore 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#kotlin+ktx

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700 (seven hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: However, I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) might help.

Comment: First of all: Welcome to Stackoverflow, we are happy that you are here. But I can only give @AlexMamo a +1 for his comment.

Comment: I have simplified my question please review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938465/how-to-swipe-delete-recyclerview-item-from-cloud-firestore-with-the-help-of-kotl

Answer (score 0):

You will need an ItemTouchHelper Callback Method in order to implement swipe to delete in Android Recycler view. something like this below

```
abstract class SwipeToDeleteCallback internal constructor(internal var mContext: Context) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
private val mClearPaint: Paint
private val mBackground: ColorDrawable
private val backgroundColor: Int
private val deleteDrawable: Drawable?
private val intrinsicWidth: Int
private val intrinsicHeight: Int


init {
    mBackground = ColorDrawable()
    backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#b80f0a")
    mClearPaint = Paint()
    mClearPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
    deleteDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_delete)
    intrinsicWidth = deleteDrawable!!.intrinsicWidth
    intrinsicHeight = deleteDrawable.intrinsicHeight
}


override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
    return ItemTouchHelper.Callback.makeMovementFlags(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT)
}

override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, viewHolder1: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun onChildDraw(
     c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView,  viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float,
    dY: Float,
    actionState: Int,
    isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
) {
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

    val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
    val itemHeight = itemView.height

    val isCancelled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive

    if (isCancelled) {
        clearCanvas(
            c,
            itemView.right + dX,
            itemView.top  + 0f,
            itemView.right + 0f,
            itemView.bottom + 0f
        )
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
        return
    }

    mBackground.color = backgroundColor
    mBackground.setBounds(itemView.right + dX.toInt(), itemView.top, itemView.right, itemView.bottom)
    mBackground.draw(c)

    val deleteIconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
    val deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
    val deleteIconLeft = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth
    val deleteIconRight = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin
    val deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight


    deleteDrawable!!.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom)
    deleteDrawable.draw(c)

    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)


}

private fun clearCanvas(c: Canvas, left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
    c.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mClearPaint)

}

override fun getSwipeThreshold(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Float {
    return 0.7f
}
```

}

Then you can use like this

```
recyclerView..addOnItemTouchListener(YourItemTouchHere)
```

Implement the onMove method. The to delete on firestore just set the value for the object path in firestore to FieldValue.delete() and it will be deleted