# How to swipe delete recyclerview item from cloud firestore with the help of kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

By using this code I am able to swipe recycler items correctly but the actual firesore data is not getting deleted? Is there something I am missing?

**Inside my Constants Class**

```
object Constants{
    const val USERS : String = "users"
    const val BOARDS : String = "boards"
const val DOCUMENT_ID : String = "documentId"
}
```

**Inside my firestore class**

```
fun deleteBoard(){
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.BOARDS).document(Constants.DOCUMENT_ID).delete()
    }
```

**Inside my adapter class**

```
open class BoardItemsAdapter(private val context: Context,private var list: ArrayList<Board>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()

var lists = mutableListOf<Board>()
    init {
        this.lists = list as MutableList<Board>
    }


 fun del(position: Int){
        FirestoreClass().deleteBoard()
        lists.removeAt(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

**Swipe To delete class**

```
abstract class SwipeToDelete(context: Context,dragDir : Int,swipeDir : Int) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(dragDir,swipeDir){
    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        
    }
}
```

**And finally inside main activity**

```
fun populateBoardsListToUI(boardsList: ArrayList<Board>) {
    hideProgressDialog()

    if (boardsList.size > 0) {
        rv_boardList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        tv_noBoardsAvailable.visibility = View.GONE

        rv_boardList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rv_boardList.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val adapter = BoardItemsAdapter(this, boardsList)
        rv_boardList.adapter = adapter

        adapter.setOnClickListener(object : BoardItemsAdapter.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(position: Int, model: Board) {
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, TaskListActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.DOCUMENT_ID, model.documentId)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })

        val item = object : SwipeToDelete(this, 0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                adapter.del(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
            }
        }

        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(item)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_boardList)


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the delete operation to see if something is wrong?

Comment: I added log statements inside success and failure listeners.               
Log.i("FireStoreDel", "Item Deleted Successfully")                                                                        Log.e("FireStoreDel", "Error Occured with exception $e")                                                               But the logcat result showed Item Deleted Successfully

Comment: So it works, right?

Comment: Yeah, the deleteBoard function works but it's not actually deleting the items from cloud firestore.

Comment: One question, every time a position (a particular field in document "documentId") is deleted, do you delete the entire document?